# How to undo "write" in SWI-Prolog while tracing?

Tags: swi-prolog

We can type "w" during trace if we want Prolog to display everything in the current and following calls (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,%272.9%27,swi(%27/doc/Manual/debugoverview.html%27))).

Is there a way to turn it off, so that it stops displaying everything from that point onward? Something like `[nowrite]`? I couldn't find this in the document or find a similar question.

----- Edit ------

When we type "w", it will write out everything on the screen. Then if we press [Enter] (or 'l' or 'r' or other commands that leads us to another call), the subsequent calls would still be written out version. So my question is, how to resume to the un-written out version when going to another call, that nullifies our previous typing of "w"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two commands affect the terms written by the debugger: `w` and `p`. The second one may provide what you want. You can also type a `b` (break) and then use the `set_prolog_flag/2` predicate to set the `debugger_write_options` to the options you want.

Comment: Sorry I guess I did not articulate the question clearly. I'll try again in edit.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! "P" is exactly what I wanted.